# Getting/setting columns with IColumnManager from C#/F#

Tags: winapi, f#, shell-extensions

I want to get and set visible columns in the Details View. I have a shell extension (implemented with a 3rd party library), and I add a menu item to the context menu when the user right-clicks on the folder background. By adding IObjectWithSite to my extension, I've been able to get the interface to IColumnManager.

There is no declaration for IColumnManager on www.pinvoke.net, and the only example of calling it that I have found in .NET is in a defunct branch of BExplorer. Based on that, I got GetColumnCount() working.

```
let mutable colCount = 0u;
columnManager.GetColumnCount (CM_ENUM_FLAGS.CM_ENUM_VISIBLE, &colCount)
```

(I'm working in F#. But for now I'm using C# to declare the interfaces and structures).

It looks like my next step is to get a PROPERTYKEY array by calling GetColumns(). This is defined as

```
HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *GetColumns )( 
    __RPC__in IColumnManager * This,
    /* [in] */ CM_ENUM_FLAGS dwFlags,
    /* [size_is][out] */ __RPC__out_ecount_full(cColumns) PROPERTYKEY *rgkeyOrder,
    /* [in] */ UINT cColumns);
```

And here is an example doing it from C++, taken from http://blogs3805.rssing.com/chan-16291381/all_p568.html:

```
PROPERTYKEY *columns = new PROPERTYKEY[nColumns];
            hr = pColumnManager->GetColumns(CM_ENUM_VISIBLE, 
                                            columns, 
                                            nColumns);
```

BExplorer has this for GetColumns:

```
void GetColumns(CM_ENUM_FLAGS dwFlags, [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] PropertyKey[] rgkeyOrder, uint cColumns);
```

But it seems to me that SizeParamIndex would be needed here, since I'm marshaling an array. So I've also tried

```
void GetColumns([In] CM_ENUM_FLAGS dwFlags, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] PROPERTYKEY[] columns, [In] uint colCount);
```

Neither one works. When I do this

```
let columns = Array.init (int colCount) (fun i -> PROPERTYKEY())
columnManager.GetColumns (CM_ENUM_FLAGS.CM_ENUM_VISIBLE, columns, colCount)
```

I get a System.AccessViolationException with HResult=0x80004003.

Comment: [In] on dwFlags and colCount are useless. How do you define PROPERTYKEY? I know nothing about F#, but you must allocate an array of colCount*sizeof(PROPERTYKEY) bytes before making the call. Have you checked you have a decent colCount? Also, can you show the full definition of IColumnManager? check the IID is correct, order of methods is important.

Comment: @SimonMourier Indeed, somewhere in my fidgeting with the IColumnManager interface, I swapped the order of GetColumns() and SetColumns(). Fixing that solved my problem (and I understand why). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You should answer yourself if you're happy.

Comment: I second the recommendation to answer your own question (and accept that answer once the system lets you do so, which IIRC will be 48 hours later). Seeing that the question has an accepted answer means that anyone in the future who has a similar problem, and searches and finds this question in their search results, will know that they can look here to find an answer.

Comment: I posted the answer. I'd like to include the proper declaration of the IColumnManager interface in the answer, in case it's useful to someone in the future. But, I only have the last three function calls working. I can't get GetColumnInfo() to work (haven't tried SetColumnInfo() yet). So here's what I have  - at least, the functions here are in the correct order. [Edit] can't post code in the comment, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that while fidgeting with the C# interface declaration for IColumnManager, I had changed the order of two functions. The order of functions has to match the order that will be found in the vtable at runtime.